# How do I have "asperrorpath" displayed with the query string?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, custom-errors

In my ASP.NET MVC3 application when I queue some request to `/Controller/Action?param=whatever` and it fails and IIS custom errors handling configured in web.config kicks in and performs a "default redirect" (which is configured to redirect to `/GenericHandler.htm` I get redirected to `/GenericHandler.htm?aspxerrorpath=/Controller/Action` and the query string (`param=wheveter` part) is lost.

How do I make the query string preserved?

Comment: plz post code of action you want to invoke..

Comment: @Exception: `throw new InvalidOperationException()` would be enough.